# Using socketio with react redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, react-redux

Im building a small chat application using react,redux,socketio and node with mongoose. Normally redux flows through actions (which makes API calls and receive data) and dispatch the data. But in my case the socket will emit to a certain event but it would not return data until we manually emit the data from the back-end. so to achieve the proper redux flow should i add a socket event on actions to retrieve the data (coming from back-end) and then dispatch it or is there any other proper way to achieve this?

Here is a sample code of what i'm planing to do in
**Actions** file

```
    function sendMessage(data) {
      return {
        type: SEND_MESSAGE,
        payload: data
      };
    }

    export const sendNewMessage = (socket,data) => {
         return dispatch => {
              socket.emit("send message",data);
              socket.on("new message",function(data){
                  dispatch(sendMessage(data));
               });


    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems perfectly reasonable to me. I would suggest using thunk's "extra argument" for this such that your components do not need to know about the actual socket object:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ socket }))
)

export const sendNewMessage = (data) =>
  (dispatch, getState, { socket }) => {
    socket.emit("send message", data)
    socket.on("new message", (data) => {
      dispatch(sendMessage(data))
    })
  }
```

Comment: this gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined`

Comment: did you apply the extra argument (the socket)? when you applied the middleware? where are you initializing the socket?

Comment: Yes i did initialize it in store where we apply the middleware

Comment: strange what version of redux-thunk are you using? can you paste your initialization code?

Comment: can you also paste the code that throws the undefined error?

Comment: you can find the code fore store in this link `https://gist.github.com/TRomesh/b3ea82bdeb70fa27f7edd1f083a2cb49`

Comment: that link gives me 404. is your gist private? you should probably just edit your question with the code. that would be the correct thing to do